# WinUI3 Getting the index of a ListView right clicked item (C++)

Tags: c++, .net, winui-3

I'm trying to get the index of a ListView Item that is right clicked, but it doesn't work.

This is how the XAML code looks like

```
<ListView
    Name="ProjectsListView"
    RightTapped="OnListViewRightTapped"
    SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C++

```
void FirstPage::OnListViewRightTapped(
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const &,
      winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Input::RightTappedRoutedEventArgs const &e)
{
  auto a = e.OriginalSource().as<DependencyObject>();
  auto index = ProjectsListView().IndexFromContainer(a);
}
```

`index` is 0xffffffff

Do you know what the problem might be, or an example of code that is working?

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFF` is also known as `-1` as that method returns a signed int. That value [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.indexfromcontainer?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4#microsoft-ui-xaml-controls-itemscontrol-indexfromcontainer(microsoft-ui-xaml-dependencyobject)) means container not found. It's highly likely your `as` cast is potentially failing.

Comment: Tapped events are UIElement events, there's nothing that relates them to a list view or a selection. You only get the source which is like a TextBlock here (child of Button). Why do you need the index anyway? Can't you just use databinding? ie: get the bound object from ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext ?

Comment: @SimonMourier That's the way to the answer, I used e.OriginalSource().as<FrameworkElement>().DataContext().as<winrt::hstring>();

Answer (score 0):

#### [`int IndexFromContainer(DependencyObject const& container)` Returns:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.indexfromcontainer?view=winrt-22621#returns)

> The index to the item that corresponds to the specified generated container,
> **or `-1` if container is not found**.

#### [`OriginalSource()` Definition:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.routedeventargs.originalsource?view=winrt-22621#definition)

> Gets a reference to the object that raised the event.
> This **is often a template part of a control** rather than an element that was declared in your app UI.

In my experience, on x64 `sizeof (int) == 4` is effectively always true.
However, the C++ standard only requires [at least 16bits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) for the `int` type.
As of C++20 integers are always represented as two's complement. (See: [P1236R1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1236r1.html)).
Therefore:
`-1 == static_cast<int> (0xffffffff)` is true (at least for 32bits and lower integer size). ([Live on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/E95MsdW9q)).